# How use summery element for label in cell of table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row, nsindexpath

I have label in my custom cell. That cell i have display with a table view. Now i have problem is that when text of label is more wider than cell width then text cross cell width. So how summarize that text so that after a sufficient length text show ....  How do that?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one line, you can also use

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

to reduce the size of the font to fit the text. This will work as long as the necessary font size is not less than the label's `minimumFontSize` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UILabel and set its frame to the rectangle that you would like the text to be displayed. You can set the numberOfLines property. The end of the text will be automatically truncated for you and replaced with "..." .

Answer (score 0):

Do this to your label

> label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;